# How do I correct this vba code?

Tags: vba, range

I am still new to vba.

I am trying to create a new function however, it keeps giving me an output that I am not expecting.

my code is as follows:

```
Function bonusplanA(a, b, c)

    Dim example As Range
    Set example = Range("a:c")

    Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(example, ">=90")
    Value1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(example, ">=80")

    If Value = 3 Then
      bonusplanA = "$20,000 bonus"
    Else
      If Value1 = 3 Then
      bonusplanA = "$10,000 bonus"
      Else
        bonusplanA = "NO BONUS"
      End If
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on the output you're expecting and the actual output?

Comment: okay, i am working on a problem that requires me to state the bonus plan. The output is supposed to be "$20,000 bonus", "$10,000 bonus" or "NO BONUS". But i keep getting 0 or #value.

the bonus plan is dependent on 3 inputs (a, b and c), if all three are more than 90 it is $20,000 or if all are >= 80, it is $10,000 and NO BONUS otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that part was clear. What you need to describe is: **1.** what input are you working on; **2.** what output do you expect (and why) **3.** what output do you actually get

Comment: the inputs of a, b and c are integers. but i am trying to make a,b and c inputs as a selection range from anywhere in the sheet.


however, my output i have been getting is #value! or 0.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your function like this:

```
Function bonusplanA(a, b, c)

    If a >= 90 And b >= 90 And c >= 90 Then
        bonusplanA = "$20,000 bonus"
    Else
        If a >= 80 And b >= 80 And c >= 80 Then
            bonusplanA = "$10,000 bonus"
        Else
            bonusplanA = "NO BONUS"
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

The problem in your example was that `Range("a:c")` does not make a range of your `a,b,c` variables; instead it selects the range composed of columns A, B and C.

You need to use parameters `a`, `b` and `c` directly, not through the `Range` function.

Otherwise, the logic was sound. :)